# reference .Net framework 4.5.2 from .Net Core 2.0 project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-framework-version

I have spent a few hours trying to figure out why .Net Core 2.0 wouldn't load .Net framework 4.5.2 nuget packages.

Now I think it's time to ask...

What happens is I have a .Net Core 2.0 WebApi app (A) and I want to reuse my .Net framework 4.5.2 library(B).

I created nuget packages for B and referenced the nuget package in the A.

The libraries are downloaded in the C:\Users\username.nuget\packages folder
But when I consume B in the code, it errors me out saying

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
>   'xxx.TradeServices.Common, Version=2.1.289.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. The located assembly's manifest definition does
>   not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)'

I then added some dummy code

```
var client = new TradeServicesClient(EnvironmentType.Production);
```

xxx.TradeServices.Common is loaded.

But another exception appear
saying cannot load dependency dll.

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Ice,
>   Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0c5ebb72d74932c6'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I have checked all the dependencies, they are downloaded correctly in the

> C:\Users\username.nuget\packages

folder

I am not sure about why .Net Core is behaving this way. It seems the dependency chain is not loaded. Could you please help me to figure out what's going on?

Comment: asp.net core? or .net core? despite the names, they're kinda different

Comment: what you are describing is fundamentally not supported; you should change B to multi-target, i.e. B should target net452 **and** netstandard2.0 (or some earlier netstandard)

Comment: asp.net core 2.0

Comment: "asp.net core" doesn't know whether it is going to be running on .net core or .net framework or something else; best to consume things that target .net standard

Comment: How about the dependencies of B? I can't change the dependencies of B to netstandard2.0...

Comment: does your asp.net core app know that it is actually targeting .net framework? more specifically: what is the `<TargetFramework>` in your csproj for the asp.net core application?

Comment: <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>

Comment: that's the problem then; change that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

asp.net core can target multiple frameworks; a 2.0 web app will typically run on either "netcoreapp2.0" (a .NET Core application) or "net461" (a .NET application), for example - as specified by the `<TargetFramework>` in the csproj. It is this `<TargetFramework>` that determines how all the downstream package resolution will work. If it is "net461", it may be happy to take a "net452" library. However, "netcoreapp2.0" will not want "net452" - instead preferring "netstandard2.0" or "netstandard1.6", etc. Targeting .NET Standard will mean that all downstream packages *also* need to target .NET Standard, which is not always possible.

So:

- if possible, make your dependencies target some version of .NET Standard
- if that isn't possible, ensure that the `<TargetFramework>` is "net461" or similar

---

Edit: it looks like the default projects *also* change between `Microsoft.AspNetCore` (when targeting .NET) and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` (when targeting .NET Core) - so you may also need to change that `<PackageReference ... />` entry in the csproj. If you are using any of the extra packages in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`  that aren't in `Microsoft.AspNetCore` - you may need to add the ones that you need manually.

Comment: Now It's saying Microsoft.Asp.NetCore.All 2.0.5 is not compatible with net461

Comment: @Larry change that to `Microsoft.AspNetCore` - no `.All`; if other bits are missing, you might need to add in individual components

Answer (score 2):

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54116368/10891544

To target multiple frameworks from a .net core project, open up your .csproj file and replace the TargetFramework tag with a new TargetFrameworks tag:

`<TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>`

This should allow you to use .NET Framework packages from a .NET Core project.  However, you will lose the ability to run your code cross-platform.