# Dapper: Cannot read/map Geometry type field in local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I am running ASP.NET Core 2 application.

I have a local instance of SQL Server where I have a table with a column of type `Geometry`.

When I go to read this table I get the following errors:

> Type Udt is not supported on this platform.
>   Error parsing column 4 (MyLocation)

However this issue only seems to occur in my API project which calls to a custom made Nuget package that handles the CRUD operations.

If I test the same code in the project that does the CRUD it reads and maps my object.

It is not a connection issue in the API for I can successfully read/write other tables that do not have a Geometry field in it.

What could I possible be missing?

Code:

MyController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid Id)
{
   var rec = await myRepo.Get<MyData>(id);
   // then do stuff
}
```

*myRepo is injected into my controller.

```
public class MyData
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public IGeometry MyLocation {get;set;}
}
```

myRepo:

```
public async Task<TEntity> Get<TEntity>(object id)
where TEntity : class
{
   _conn.Open();
   return await _conn.GetAsync<TEntity>(id);
}
```

Comment: asp.net-core is ambiguous - is this running on .net core? or .net framework? (asp.net core can run on both)

Comment: It is running on .Net Core 2.0

Answer (score 1):

If this is .NET Core, then I suspect you could have significant issues using sqlgeography etc; UDTs essentially aren't yet implemented in .NET Core:

[image]

Additionally, the underlying types that you would want to load use native code; the geo/etc types are not, AFAIK, available in .NET Core.

If I'm wrong, I'm more than happy to try to make whatever changes we need to help make this work, but at the time of writing: I don't think this is going to work *through any API* (it is not specific to Dapper).

You might want to consider using ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework for today? [reference .Net framework 4.5.2 from .Net Core 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49534543/23354)

If this data *does* actually load from ADO.NET in .NET Core, then I'd be happy to fix whatever I've missed.

Comment: Hmm; *apparently* there's `Microsoft.Spatial` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Spatial/) - but I'm unclear how to map that to the UDT issue... since historically UDT has been a necessary part of this story (at least when sending data *to* the server)

Comment: We cannot easily switch to the standard framework.  However we had previously solved this issue by using the Query methods and registering a SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler and adding code to map the Geometry fields.  However we since refactored and now use the Dapper.Contrib.Extension methods so the custom mapping that we thought was happening in no longer getting called.