# Does my whole solution have to be .NET Framework rather than .NET Core just because I use a NuGet package that needs the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core solution comprising 3 parts:

1. ASP.NET Core website
2. Business Logic .NET Core DLL
3. Data-access .NET Core DLL

I now have a need to use a .NET *Framework* NuGet package (which is not within my control) from my business-logic DLL.

Following the advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49534954/98422), I changed my business-logic project to target .NET 4.6.1 (net461).

However, this then forced me to do the same for the Data-access project (which is referenced from the Business-logic project), and (though I haven't got there yet) I presume I'll *also* have to do that for the website project.

I thought that .NET Core is largely a subset of .NET Framework, and that there would be no functional change beyond merely requiring the "bigger" framework,
which would be OK. However, having re-targeted my data-access project, I now find that there's some stuff missing. For example, it now objects to me using C#7 value tuples.

Although I can add back the value tuples via a NuGet package, there are other changes I need to make (DataAnnotations seems to have gone/moved), and it rather seems like I'm drifting back towards *everything* being done the .NET Framework way.

Is there any way around this? I feel like I'm pulling on a piece of string that will end up with me going all the way back to ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: I had a similar issue like this recently... I would suggest to go through the effort to reorganize your projects so that you make one project your "framework bridging" (that is .NET 4.6) and another which is the .NET Core project. You will ultimately end up with two applications (one .NET 4.6 the other .NET Standard)

Comment: @Svek: I don't mind taking the time to do it right, but I don't actually see how. If I make my Business Logic project .NET 4.6 then it won't let the Data Access project remain as .NET Core. So as soon as I have one project on .NET 4.6 the whole tree seems to be "contaminated".

Comment: Here is a small idea of what I mean that you could expand and grow on for now (I will write up an answer when I have some time). Create a project using .NET Standard (read carefully) then in the project create an object called Foo and give a couple basic properties. This project must remain isolated from pulling any dependencies that are not NET Standard. You can reference this object in both the .NET Core and .NET Framework... Let's use an API (such as web API) and pass this object (Foo) between the two applications. So we have 2 apps + 1 shared class library to bridge them together...

Comment: A one line answer: .NET Standard is the lowest common ground between the two, so create an isolated .NET Standard class library and use that to bridge your two incompatible apps.

Comment: @Svek: do you mean two separate applications that run as separate processes and communicate by HTTP? In the context of the 3-layer (web/logic/data) architecture I described, that's almost like recursion! :-) The logic layer would need to be expanded to have its own web API??? I'm so confused. I wish I hadn't started down this road.

Comment: You can choose your favorite brand of API, even named pipes could work. The main point is that the two projects are not compatible until you can make your dependencies .NET Standard.

Comment: To justify this endeavor, consider it as shifting your architecture to a micro services pattern. This kind of decoupling will allow the business layer to be built on rusty ancient code, while your front will get a facelift.

Comment: @Svek: the problem is that the NuGet package I need to use is not mine - I have no control over it, and so it will remain .NET 4. My original question was "does my whole solution now have to be changed", and I think you're saying the answer is "yes". Any projects in the same solution will all have to change. I can have a *completely separate* solution to isolate the "old" stuff, and talk to it "over the phone", but I can't incorporate it into my existing solution. That's astonishing - and devastating.

Comment: There's no way I can justify building a whole new application (and cross-application API) just to support this one single function. Even just setting up the deployment mechanism for that would be a large amount of work. So it looks like I need to abandon .NET Core. And in turn I guess that means I need to abandon ASP.NET Core... and so many weeks of hard work on my web project are wasted :-(((

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to target both frameworks at the same time.  I worked on a project where I wanted to target .Net core 2.0 but needed to use a .NET Framework package.

To do this, open up your .csproj file and replace the TargetFramework tag with a new TargetFrameworks tag

`<TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>`

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to do this through the UI in visual studio.  After you make this change and reload Visual Studio, your target framework will just be blank.

Comment: I was hopeful, but this doesn't seem to help. If I make my Business Logic project target both Core and Framework, then it complains that my Data Access project 
 (which targets Core) isn't compatible. If I make the Data Access project also target both Core and Framework, then it won't compile because it doesn't have ValueTuple and DataAnnotations etc. - which is where I was before. Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think this answer is missing the point somewhat. I'm not trying to create a library that can be used by two different .NET versions. Because my web project is an ASP .NET Core web app, my library needs to be used by ASP.NET Core. So multi-targeting the business-logic DLL doesn't help unless it's compatible with ASP.NET Core, and from what I gather that's not possible if it has a .NET Framework dependency. (So apparently I'm out of options).

Answer (score 0):

Having convinced myself during my chat with @Svek that I'd have to abandon my whole web project and start again with an old-style ASP.NET MVC web project (or slit my wrists), I've now discovered that this is not the case.

Here's what I think are the salient points:

1. If you're using a NuGet package that uses .NET 4.6 then you *cannot* use that in a DLL that targets .NET Core.
2. You *can* (per @Matt H's answer) have a DLL that targets *both* .NET Core and .NET 4.6 - but that doesn't really help, since all that does is create two versions of the DLL, and only the .NET 4.6 version can use the NuGet package. So, your DLL needs to target .NET 4.6.
3. By extension every project in your solution that directly *references* that DLL also needs to target .NET 4.6. So yes, the contagion does spread. :-(
4. In my case, that meant that my ASP.NET Core web app *also* needed to target .NET 4.6 - and I assumed at first that this meant abandoning ASP.NET Core altogether, and throwing away a considerable amount of work I'd done on my web project. **However** this is not the case.
5. It *is* possible to have an ASP.NET Core web app run on .NET 4.6 (even though that seems somehow illogical). In fact, when creating a new ASP.NET Core web application in Visual Studio, you can choose to target .NET 4.6 at that point. This produces a different project file, with extra NuGet dependencies etc. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37452041/98422).

So, my eventual solution was:

1. Changed all my DLLs to target "net461" (by editing the project file).
2. "Polyfilled" some of the stuff that was missing as a result (e.g. by adding a NuGet package to get ValueTuple support, and by adding an explicit package reference to get System.Component.DataAnnotations).
3. Hacked around the ASP.NET Core web project to also target "net461" which then meant updating various references and adding more NuGet packages to get the ASP.NET Core components working. (I created two versions of a new web project - one targeting .NET Core and one targeting .NET 4.6 - in order to see what the difference was, and thus what changes I had to make).

Having done all this, my project compiles and runs correctly. Which is a *huge* relief.

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out. Since ASP.NET Core is using .NET Standard you can always target `NET4.6` as it is compatible. For future reference it is important to note that ASP.NET Core is not the same as .NET Core! :)   Anyway, the only thing you have lost is the ability to compile your application for cross-platform.

Comment: My initial understanding since your question was asked was that the objective was to get the code to remain .NET Core (ie. cross-platform & .NET Standard) --- however, it seems we had some misunderstanding and you didn't mind targeting `NET46` afterall. Which is where much of the confusion lies.

Comment: @Svek: sorry, I agree my question - and subsequent questions - have been woolly. That's because this is all new to me, and so I didn't really know how to frame the question. As you guessed, I was also confused about the relationship between ASP.NET Core and .NET Core. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm happy you got it sorted. That's what is important!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (albeit perhaps not what you want) is to separate your project into smaller projects, where the business and data logic can then be converted to services (SOA - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture)

This might seem to be "the long way round", but it does have it's eventual advantages in that the separated logic services and the main project are independent of each other in terms of technology and most other requirements.

Again, I realize this might not be what you're after, but I felt it's a valid option, and possibly useful to share here.

Comment: That's what @Svek was getting at in his comments. I get it, but I think it's outrageously expensive considering the benefit that accrues, especially in a corporate environment where release/deployment pipelines would be required for all those new components. Expensive, that is, relative to the near-zero benefit (to me) of developing in .NET Core as opposed to .NET Framework.

Comment: @GaryMcGill I fully understand your feeling. Unfortunately .Net Core is still fairly new compared to .Net Framework, but it is ever growing and there release of .Net Core 3.0 is just around the corner, which bring many many new things to the table. Granted that does not help you right now, but perhaps someone else can benefit from your question and the answers & comments posted here.